# Weight scale using android

Tags: android

I need to weigh the object which is placed on a android touch screen(Mobile) without using any physical measurement device. I tried to do with the android in built sensors but I could not find the amount pressure.How to find it.Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user asks for the impossible.

Comment: In most cases, our displays are **capacitive**. They don't measure `pressure`, but `contact` (with a grounded conductive mean). I'm not sure for **resistive** displays, but they are going to disappear soon, as they are inefficient.

Comment: Then what about the weight scale apps available on googleplay store.Are they all fake apps?.If not then let me know how do they calculate the weight of an object.

Comment: I have no idea. But they simply **can't**. also, would it make sense? `What can you measure?` your weight? the device will break. a stamp? the device would't be sensible enough. not even for a resistor. SO... what would be the utility, if it could be done?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if your device support `Force Touch` which is not supported in almost every android device up to now.

Visit here `http://www.theverge.com/2015/9/2/9244651/huawei-mate-s-force-touch` for more information.

But,

> There are still a lot of questions about Huawei's Force Touch technology, namely, how accurate is it and what is the maximum weight? The orange weighed in the demonstration came out as 280 grams, which sounds a little on the heavy side to us, but it's clear that Huawei has big ambitions when it comes to moving beyond basic touchscreen interactions.